# Mock base class method in chain template inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, googletest, googlemock

Suppose you have a template class like the one below which inherit from a wide range of other classes.

```
template<typename T> 
class Generic : public T
{
    //implementation
}
```

It's not allowed to modify class `Generic`. To overcome this I write a wrapper to this class which inherit a specific type of `Generic` class. Inside this class I mocked a virtual method from class `A`

```
class Wrapper: public Generic<A>
{
    MOCK_METHOD2(methodFromA,void(int a,int b));
}
```

Then I write a test which looks like this. The problem is that I get segmentation fault when `EXPECT_CALL` is invoked. Calling other methods from class `A` works as expected.

```
TEST(classA, TC0)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Wrapper> wrapper = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Wrapper>(functionReturnPointerToA())
    if(wrapper)
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(1,methodFromAwhichReturns1()); //it works
        EXPECT_CALL(*wrapper,methodFromA(_,_); //segmentation fault
    }
}
```

I also tried template specialization but this doesn't seems to works either since MOCK_METHOD is an preprocessor directive

```
template <> inline Wrapper<A>::MOCK_METHOD2(methodFromA,void(int a,int b));
```

Comment: Do you really mean `class Wrapper: public T<A>`? I think `class Wrapper: public Generic<A>` makes more sense.

Comment: You are right. It was a typo. I will modify

Comment: What object does `functionReturnPointerToA` actually create? Does it create a `Wrapper` or does it create another object derived from `A`?

Comment: It returns a shared pointer to A

Comment: "Google Mock requires expectations to be set before the mock functions are called, otherwise the behavior is undefined." https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md

Comment: "This means EXPECT_CALL() should be read as expecting that a call will occur in the future, not that a call has occurred." from there as well.

Comment: Can you please detail what do you mean by setting expectation before calling mock function?

Comment: It is hard to believe that the given code would have a segmentation fault, because the if-block should never be entered. The dynamic cast should always deliver a null-ptr if `functionReturnPointerToA()` really returns an `A`, because `A` is not a `Wrapper`.